# Multiple SelectedValuePath/SelectedValue binding on ComboBox with List<Tuple<long, long, string>> ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a `ComboBox` which has an `ItemSource` of `List<Tuple<long, long, string>>`. In the tuple `Item3` is some user-friendly display text, `Item1` and `Item2` are two different (but 1-to-1 related) sequences/keys that I need to update on a bound object when the user changes the selected item.

I can bind one of these sequences easily enough like this:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, Mode=OneWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Item3"
          SelectedValuePath="Item1"
          SelectedValue="{Binding MyObject.FirstSequence, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

What I am trying to achieve is something like:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList, Mode=OneWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Item3"
          SelectedValuePath1="Item1"
          SelectedValue1="{Binding MyObject.FirstSequence, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath2="Item2"
          SelectedValue2="{Binding MyObject.SecondSequence, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this, perhaps with multibinding?

I have tried setting `MyObject.SecondSequence` in the setter of `MyObject.FirstSequence` however `MyObject.FirstSequence` and `MyObject.SecondSequence` are also populated from a database initially and I only need to update them both when the user makes a change, so this would add quite a bit of additional and unnecessary overhead in 99% of cases.

I could potentially change `MyObject.FirstSequence` and `MyObject.SecondSequence` to a class that holds both sequences something like this:

```cs
class Sequences
{
    string DisplayText { get; set; }
    long FirstSequence { get; set; }
    long SecondSequence { get; set; }
}
```

Then set `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to `List<Sequences>` and bind to `MyObject.Sequences`, however that would mean quite a lot of other code changes and I want to explore other options first.

Comment: Since it is a view model and view models are meant to be tailored acc to the view's needs I'd recommend @Clemens approach. It's the clean and straight way to get you data where you want them both in the view and in the VM (and model).
Since MyObject seems to be partially related to the 3 tuple values it might be an idea to bind a list of MyObject to the Combo, not the tuple list, and then just select/bind the desired MyObject. But it also sounds as if this would require too much refactoring effort. And time is always precious, at least to your client...

Comment: With hindsight I'd not have gone this route in the first place, but requirements changed overtime and it's suddenly come back to bite us! Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view model could have a `SelectedTuple` property that sets the properties of `MyObject`:

```
private Tuple<long, long, string> selectedTuple;

public Tuple<long, long, string> SelectedTuple
{
    get => selectedTuple;
    set
    {
        selectedTuple = value;
        MyObject.FirstSequence = selectedTuple.Item1;
        MyObject.SecondSequence = selectedTuple.Item2;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTuple));
    }
}
```

It would be set like shown below - initially, but perhaps also in a `PropertyChanged` event handler attached to `MyObject`.

```
SelectedTuple = MyList.FirstOrDefault(t =>
    t.Item1 == MyObject.FirstSequence && t.Item2 == MyObject.SecondSequence);
```

The `SelectedTuple` property would be bound to like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTuple}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Item3"/>
```

Comment: Ah, that's probably the way to go. Thanks!