# How to deal with multiple properties for finding objects, referred by ComboBox' entries (how to add multiple entries in SelectedValuePath)?

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, binding, identification

This is a follow-up of [my previous question on a `ComboBox` in a C# WPF solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77999986).

Background: I have two classes: `Pallet` and `CUnit`. I have a list of `Pallet` objects, called `ActivePallets` and a single `CUnit`, called `Unit`.

I have the following source (in a XAML):

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Cmb_MPNr" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding ActivePallets}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Unit.MPNr, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="MPNr"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
          TextSearch.TextPath="MPNr"
          IsEditable="True">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MPNr}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>

<TextBox Name="PO" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" IsEnabled="False">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} - {1}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem.PO" ElementName="Cmb_MPNr" />
            <Binding Path="SelectedItem.Description" ElementName = "Cmb_MPNr" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

I understand (more or less) what it means: the source of the `ComboBox` is `ActivePallets`, and when choosing an `MPNr` (in the `ComboBox`), a corresponding `CUnit` will be found, and its `PO` and `Description` are shown in the `TextBox`.

The problem that I'm having, is that a `Pallet` is not uniquely defined by its `MPNr`, but by the combination of `MPNr` and `PO`.

My initial question was closed as a duplicate, because I did not understand that `SelectedItem` was not the key property (it's the combination of `SelectedValue` and `SelectedValuePath`, but now I'm still the issue that **both** `MPNr` and `PO` are to be used as input parameters, and I don't know how to do that.

For your information, in both `Pallet` and `CUnit` classes, the `MPNr` and `PO` are defined in a very simple way:

```
public int MPNr { get; set; }
public int PO   { get; set; }
```

In top of that, both `Pallet` and `CUnit` classes don't even have an explicit constructor.

How do I need to modify the definition of `Pallet` and/or `CUnit`, in order to be able to use both `MPNr` and `PO` as an input parameter for identification?

I already had a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68366407), but I don't understand how to apply in my situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a workaround, creating a new property, consisting of the concatenation of both properties:

```
public string MPNrPO { ...}
...
MPNrPO = $"{MPNr}|{PO}";
```

This is not a real solution: instead of understanding how to use two parameters as an input parameter, I combined both into one single parameter and used that one, but it gets the job done.

One very important, but very ugly remark on the workaround:

```
public string MPNrPO {
  get
  {
    return _mPNrPO;
  }
  set
  {
    if (value != null)
    _mPNrPO = value;
    else
    { } // Sometimes MPNrPO gets set to null 
        // (the callstack is meaningless, 
        //  root cause is lack of MVVM knowledge)
  }
}
```